# ¿Cómo eliminar un valor de un campo para que no se pueda mostrar? Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

### Formulario

```
class PerfilForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PerfilForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.num_cc:
            num = ''
            for i in range(len(self.instance.num_cc[:-3])):
                num += '*'
            self.fields['num_cc'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': num + self.instance.num_cc[-3:]})
        self.fields['num_cc'].initial = ''

    class Meta:
        model = Perfil
        fields = ['tel','tel_fijo','entrg_pais','entrg_dep','entrg_ciudad','entrg_direccion',
                    'entrg_cp','rmt_pais','rmt_dep','rmt_direccion','rmt_ciudad','rmt_cp',
                    'num_cc','avatar','propietario_cc','banco','tipo_cc','tipo_ident','cedula_o_nit','descp_armario',
                    'acepta_politicas']
```

Estoy intentando limpiar el valor `num_cc` para que no aparezca en mi formulario aunque esté relleno pero si está relleno siempre me aparece y no exactamente como poder hacerlo

Comment: Hola, esto tendrías que hacerlo en tu vista. Tal vez puedes mostrar tu vista para poder ayudarte.

Comment: he conseguido solucionarlo, he modificacdo el kwargs['num_cc'] y después ejecuta el super(), de esta forma si tiene algún valor lo elimino para que no se muestre.